# Tracking skeleton with hand coordinates using windows form c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am currently doing a picking project which i need my hand to have coordinates. i got the skeleton tracking down but i got no idea or reference to start on the hand coordinates, is there any where i could find codes or reference on how to achieve this?

```
Frame frame = controller.Frame (); // controller is a Controller object
HandList hands = frame.Hands;
Hand firstHand = hands [0];


Frame frame = controller.Frame (); // controller is a Controller object
HandList hands = frame.Hands;

Hand leftmost = hands.Leftmost;
Hand rightmost = hands.Rightmost;
Hand frontmost = hands.Frontmost;
```

this is the codes i found for getting hand coordinates but i cant display it on the user interface.

Comment: There is no way to answer properly since there is no information on what the code is, is there some framework, what coordinates you're talking about etc. Please add a lot more information.

Comment: // Used to calcute the minimum and maximum points of object in xy plane
            int xmin = 10000;
            int xmax = -1;
            int ymin = 10000;
            int ymax = -1;

Comment: // Color point top of detected object is used to calculate the distance of the object from kinect
            float deltaX = cpt.X - 0;
            float deltaY = cpt.Y - 0;
            float deltaZ = cpt.Z - 0;   

            //Calculating distance
            float Distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);
         }

Comment: //Initilized new 2D index array of size 1080 X 1920
              float[,] index = new float[1080, 1920];                 
          

         //Applying Graphics to Image for drawing detected object's point.
            Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(PointCloudImage);
i initialize the PointCloudImage but its still have red lines under it, no idea whats the problem

Comment: Please edit the information into the question so it's clear and concise and add appropriate tags.

Comment: //Used to calcute the minimum and maximum points of object in xy plane   int xmin = 10000;
            int xmax = -1;
            int ymin = 10000;
            int ymax = -1;       This is the first part of my codes

Comment: // Applying Graphics to Image for drawing detected object's point.
            Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(PointCloudImage);               i already initialized the PointCloudImage but it stil has red error and i do not know how to display on kinect the hand with coordinates with it